# Navigate to another page based on the callout clicked

Tags: iphone, navigation, android-mapview, callout

hi i have mapview and displaying two pins with callouts and when clicked on first pin callout say it have to navigate to firstview controller and when clicked on second pin callout it have to navigate to second view controller how to check the conditon.

Answer (score 0):

Add disclosure button to your pins. Assign tags to those buttons and then simply check and navigate according to your assigned tags.

LIKE:

In your callout class (subclass of `MKAnnotationView`), add following lines in function `- (id) initWithAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier`

```
UIButton *btn;
btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
btn.frame = CGRectMake(275,27 ,30, 30);
[btn addTarget:self action:@selector(openDetail:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self.contentView addSubview:btn];
```

Tell me if it helps.

**openDetail:**

```
 -(void)openDetail: (id)sender
 {

UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;
int tag = button.tag;
 if(tag = 1)
 {
   //open 1st Controller.
 }
 else if(tag == 2)
 { 
  //open 2nd Controller.
 } 

 }
```

Comment: no actually i have two conditions two check here when userlocation pin is clicked it have to navigate to one page and when clicked on remainig pins it have to navigate to another page .

Comment: -(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control         in this method i have to check the condition of which pin is clicked

Comment: Follow all the steps in my answer and thn tell me your issue.

Comment: Debugg all the process and tell me where do u get stuck? What is creating problem? Tell me precisely

Comment: see actually i have one pin which user location when this is clicked it have to navigate on firt page and the remaining this should navigate to second page .the condition what you said is navigating to same page only

Comment: how to chat in this i dont know

Comment: Sorry u cant chat , u dnt have enough reputation!